# Partials Not Rendering in Safari Only - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari

I use "inspect" on Safari to see why... and the HTML is all there, but it just isn't visible. It is the weirdest thing to me. Works flawlessly in Chrome. I haven't encountered this before, so I am at a loss on how to debug this. Could anybody point me in a direction so I can try to debug? HTML is all there, but looks blank inside the browser. I can provide code if it helps?

Comment: Have you tried validating the HTML in a validator?  https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Please provide code.